# broadcastreceiver onReceive problem ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've found a lot of pages about this in the web, but none of them helped me. I've been for hours stucked in this problem. That's why i decided to make my own question.

What I want to do is an application that receives an intent of the type ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON and the method onReceive() of the Broadcastreceiver does something.

My Activity is like this:

```
public class MusicControlActivity extends Activity {

private MediaButtonIntentReceiver receiver = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle p_SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(p_SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        filter.setPriority(1000);
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

And my broadcastreceiver as follow:

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() 
{
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String v_IntentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(v_IntentAction)) {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent v_Event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (v_Event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int v_Action = v_Event.getAction();
    if (v_Action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    // do something
        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, no matter what I do. I've tried registering it dynamically with registerReceiver as in the code above. Also I've tried statically in the AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="10000000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And as you can see I've set the priority to a high level and even though it doesn't work. 
I've been on this for the whole day and I don't know what to do. The method onReceive from the broadcastreceiver isn't called anytime.

Does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `android:priority="2147483647"`?

Comment: No. I´ll try and i post back!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should stop using `Toast` as your diagnostic test. Use the `Log` class to log to LogCat, or breakpoints, or something.

Next, you should get rid of your `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` constructor, as it is not needed.

Then, I would dump the `if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(v_IntentAction))` block, since it is also not needed.

Next, I would make sure that your media button actually works. Does it control other applications, like a music player? It may be that your media button is not Android-compliant or something.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Ill make this changes and see what happens. Anyway the problem is not in the MediaButtonIntentReceiver class because i´ve already forced an intent using sendbroadcast() and the method onReceive works. So i think that the problem is with the intent ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON. Actually I´m testing it on the emulator and pressing the sound buttons on it? Should it work this way? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Guilherme Gusman: The emulator does not have a media button.

Comment: By the way the question that you make in the end is really important. When i´m listening to some music the media button only raises or down the volume it doesn´t change the music or something. What i´m trying to do is that, make an program to change that behavior . But now i think this button, the volume button is not the media button... is that the problem? Is yes is there any intent related to this volume button?

Comment: @Guilherme Gusman: "But now i think this button, the volume button is not the media button... is that the problem?" -- correct. "Is yes is there any intent related to this volume button?" -- no.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! haha So I can´t do what i´m trying to do... my phone wouldn´t support that! I´ll check your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON Instead in your manifest. Check : http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html